# I am facing a crash in android project for AlertDialog.dismiss and breakpoint going to Looper.java

Tags: java, android

After executing alertDialog.dismiss(), breakpoint execution going to Looper.java

```
if (alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isShowing()) {
     alertDialog.dismiss();
}
```

and I don't understand why it's going inside below if loop. Can anyone explain please.

[image]

I am running app in Huawie device with Android 10. Please let me know if I need to add more info.

Thanks in advance to everyone.

Comment: can u provide through logcat carsh result add that in your details